# Weblogic Import SSL .PFX File via Keytool

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, obiee, pfx

Recently our company is moving from LDAP to LDAPS.

We have an application (OBIEE) that runs on Weblogic with Unix as the OS. The instructions I have been provided indicate to use the java keytool command to import certificates.

Our administrator sent me a *.pfx file to import into our server. After some googling it looks like a *.pfx file can contain a few certificates within.

I figured out how to extract the certificates, but now my question is if I need to import the certificate can I use keytool to import a *.pfx file?

From the examples I have seen it doesnt sound like it can, and thus led me to extract the individual certificates. But then this leads me to my second question which is

If I have more then one certificate extracted from the *.pfx do I import ALL the certificates? Or just the root?

Not familiar with this type of thing, and any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`*.pfx` is similar to other formats e.g. `*.cert` or `*.crt` except that it contains the **private key** as well (which normally as a client of AD/LDAP server you don't need it unless you want your application to authenticate itself against AD server given this private key was generated for your application).

So you don't need to import all the certificates, only the server certificate so that your application can trust the AD/LDAP server.

1. Extract the certificate, you can do so with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/pkcs12.html) tool as follow:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.pfx -out mycerts.crt -nokeys -clcerts
```

2. Convert it from `*.crt` to `*.cer`

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in mycerts.crt -outform der -out mycerts.cer
```

3. Import the `*.cer` file into your JRE `cacerts` Keystore file.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ldap -file mycerts.cer -keystore /paht/to/your/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

**Note:** You can probably skip step 2 and import the `*.crt` file format directly to your Keystore `cacerts` file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found is to convert the `.pfx` to a `jks` keystore using the `keytool` command below. The resulting keystore will contain the private key and certificates from the pfx file :

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [pfx_to_convert.pfx] -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore [identity.jks] -deststoretype JKS
```

You will be prompted for the password you want to set for the destination keystore and of course for the password of your pfx file.

This solution was suggested at the end of this blog article :
https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/post/steps-to-create-a-jks-keystore-from-pfx-file

Now you can configure Weblogic to use the [identity.jks] keystore you just created

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SECMG/identity_trust.htm#SECMG793

After setting the keystore, in order to configure the SSL section, you will need to retrieve the alias of you private key from your keystore :

```
keytool -v -list -storetype jks -keystore [identity.jks]

[...]

Alias name: randomaliasnameformykey
Creation date: xxxx
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
```

At the beginning of the output you should see an entry of type `PrivateKeyEntry`. Then you can fill the private key alias field of your Weblogic SSL configuration with the alias name.